# block non number directive in Angular 2

Tags: angular, event-handling, angular-directive

Could be this the best angular 2-way to block non number keys using directive?

```
import {Directive,HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[blockNonNumber]'
})

export class blockNonNumberDirective {

    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event: any) {
        let keyCode = [8, 9, 37, 39, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 110];
        if ( keyCode.indexOf(event.which) === -1) event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: why is the selector in `[]` ?

Comment: You can achieve that with HTML only 
`<input type="number" min="0" step="1"/>`

Comment: putting min and step attribute doesn't prevent non number digits

Comment: @gerdi : Directive requires a CSS selector to identify the HTML in the template that is associated with the directive. The CSS selector for an attribute is the attribute name in square brackets.

Comment: @SimoneBuono yeah but why do you add it in `[]` that would imply an array an directives

Comment: that's not an array it's a css selector , [attribute]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using this to allow user to enter num only,

```
export class blockNonNumberDirective {
  constructor() { }

  @HostListener('keypress') onkeypress(e){
    let event = e || window.event;
    if(event){
      return this.isNumberKey(event);
    }
  }

  isNumberKey(event){
     let charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)){
        return false;
     }
     return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use text-mask component. it is very usefull.

````
``typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TextMaskModule } from 'angular2-text-mask';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule,
    TextMaskModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Then, use it in your component:
```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <input [textMask]="{mask: mask}" [(ngModel)]="myModel" type="text"/>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public myModel = ''
  public mask = ['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
}
```
````

[text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/blob/master/componentDocumentation.md#readme)